# Create an AzureBlobDatastore() with SDK-V2

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-python, defaultazurecredential

I am trying to create an `AzureBlobDatastore()` via the azure-sdk-v2. Previously, I successfully managed to perform the same operation via azure-sdk-v1 (from tutorial link in the next paragraph).

I am following this tutorial : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/migrate-to-v2-resource-datastore#create-a-datastore-from-an-azure-blob-container-via-account_key in order to set up/create my `AzureBlobDatastore()`.

This is the code that I am using (like in the tutorial, only updating the parameters in `MLClient.from_config()` (if I don't use the credential parameter I get an error stating that the parameter is empty):

```
ml_client = MLClient.from_config(credential=DefaultAzureCredential(),
                                 path="./workspace_config_sdk2.json")
store = AzureBlobDatastore(
    name="azureml_sdk2_blob",
    description="Datastore created with sdkv2",
    account_name=storage_account_name,
    container_name=container_name,
    protocol="wasbs",
    credentials={
        "account_key": "..my_account_key.."
    },
)

ml_client.create_or_update(store)
```

I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute
> '_to_datastore_rest_object'

Note that the `workspace_config_sdk2.json` config has the following scheme:

```
{
    "subscription_id": "...",
    "resource_group": "...",
    "workspace_name": "..."
}
```

How can I solve this error?

EDIT: On investigating the issue, it seems that it falls back to some code in "`azure\ai\ml\entities\_datastore\azure_storage.py`"

```
    175 def _to_rest_object(self) -> DatastoreData:
    176     blob_ds = RestAzureBlobDatastore(
    177         account_name=self.account_name,
    178         container_name=self.container_name,
--> 179         credentials=self.credentials._to_datastore_rest_object(),
    180         endpoint=self.endpoint,
    181         protocol=self.protocol,
    182         tags=self.tags,
    183         description=self.description,
    184     )
    185     return DatastoreData(properties=blob_ds)

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_to_datastore_rest_object'
```

Comment: Hi Timbus, it seems a bug to me, please create a bug at https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues (I'm manager of the Python SDK team at Microsoft)

Comment: Opened an issue, thank you :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To provide an update on this, As mentioned @nthandeMS we have released version 1.4.0 of azure-ai-ml. Using this version the above query can be resolved.

For more information, please refer to this link: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/28518